# Making Dev Server URLs Available Over LAN / Hosts File Config

Tags: dns

I am attempting to make a local install of nextcloud and several wordpress installs available over my local LAN:

https://localhost.devsite.org
https://nextcloudinstall.org

I am reading the Ubuntu server docs located at:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration

I understand that to achieve the above goal, that I need to create the file `/etc/netplan/99_config.yaml`

and enter configs similar to the following:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s25:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.0.100/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
          search: [mydomain, otherdomain]
          addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
```

**Question:**
My possibly, embarrassing simple question is, "how would this appear in my hosts file configuration?"

In my host file I currently have:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost  
127.0.0.1   localhost.devsite.org   *.localhost.deviste.org
127.0.0.1   nextcloudinstall.org
```

In the `/etc/hosts`, would I need to change it look like this? :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
1.1.1.1   localhost.devsite.org *.localhost.deviste.org
8.8.8.8   nextcloudinstall.org
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to test dev sites in my mobile phone over the LAN.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have several names for the localhost (127.0.0.1), the other is to use your real LAN IP ie 192.168.x.xxx, and you can have multiple entries in hosts like this

```
192.168.10.1    msrv   localhost.devsite.org nextcloudinstall.org
```

This should also precede DNS server query, and don't use random IPs (1.1.1.1 ... those are real public IPs) Local Networks are only to use the following

```
 192.168.0.0/16 or 10.0.0.0/8 or 172.16.0.0/12
```